# What documents are required to enter the Czech Republic for medical treatment?

Tags: covid-19, czech-republic

Israeli citizens can now visit the Czech Republic but [tourism is not officially permitted](https://www.mzv.cz/telaviv/en/visa_and_consular_services/coronavirus/covid19_testing_in_the_czech_republic.html):

> Travel for the purpose of tourism, or visiting friends, is not yet possible. Protective measures of the Ministry of Health of the Czech Republic include the closure of hotels and other accommodation facilities.  Among essential travel belong e.g. business meetings, exigent official meetings, court proceedings, care for children and family members, necessary hospital treatments, accompanying family members, attending funeral service, participation in education, university exams, participation in gatherings that were approved by the Ministry of Health.

If one is coming in for a medical treatment, what **exact** documents are required to be shown at the border?

> NB: I will answer this question from personal experience within two weeks. Adding it here in case someone already knows the answer.

Comment: You should contact the Czech Republic embassy and/or the Czech medical institution that you will go to , they should have the "exact" documents requirements for that kind of trip.

Comment: @Max already done. Will confirm if it works after the person in question (not myself) successfully crosses the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practical answer: no documents were requested at the port of entry to prove that the trip is for medical purposes, as of June 6th 2021. Neither did the airline ask for any. The border guard just stamped the passport and reminded the passenger about needing to quarantine.

It’s probably good to have *something* in place though, like a doctors confirmation in Czech.